# How to find datetimes where some conditions hold in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

We have a MySQL database containing bookings on different courts. Table properties (shortened):

```
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
  `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `courtId` varchar(36),
  FOREIGN KEY (`courtId`) REFERENCES `court` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Usually, bookings are paid, but under certain conditions (which I can check in the `WHERE`-part of a query), bookings can be free.

Given a court and booking duration, I want to query the next datetime at which the booking can be created for free. The conditions are not the problem, the problem is how to query not for entities but for `datetime` values.

How to realize this efficiently in MySQL?

**EDIT**: Maybe it helps to outline the conditions under which bookings are free:
The conditions under which bookings are free are dependent on how many courts are offered at the `startDate` by someone (courts are always offered except if there are special "not-offered"-bookings on that court) and how many other bookings overlapping the `startDate` are already free. This means bookings can be (and probably are) free even if there are no bookings at all in the database.

Comment: get rid of the abstract mumbo jumbo and ask your question. kind of sounds like a simple date range condition but cant really tell you without knowing more

Comment: You have a table with (at least) 2 columns: `start_date` and `end_date`?  Each row is one "booking"?  Are they `DATETIME`?  Or `DATE`?  (Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @RisingSun I have adjusted the question. Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: It would be best if you add some example scenarios to your post.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to solve this is to rephrase it as: for the given `:court_id` parameter, give me the smallest future `end_time` for which no other booking starts within the given `:duration` parameter.

This can be expressed in different ways in SQL.

With a `not exists` condition and a correlated subquery that ensures that no further booking on the same court starts within `:duration` minutes.

```
select min(b.end_date) next_possible_start_date
from bookings b
where 
    b.court_id = :court_id
    and b.end_date > now()
and not exists (
    select 1
    from bookings b1
    where 
        b.court_id = :court_id
        and b1.start_date > b.end_date
        and b1.start_date < DATE_ADD(b.end_date, interval :duration minute)
)
```

Note: if you have additional conditions, they must be repeated in the `where` clause of the query *and* of the subquery.

The same logic as `not exists` can be impemented with a `left join` antipattern

```
select min(b.end_date) next_possible_start_date
from bookings b
left join booking b1 
    on  b1.court_id = b.court_id
    and bi1.start_date > b.end_date
    and b1.start < DATE_ADD(b.end_date, interval :duration minute)
where 
    b.court_id = :court_id
    and b.end_date > now()
    and b1.court_id is null
```

In MySQL 8.0, it is also possible to use window functions: `lag()` retrieves the `start_date` of the next booking, which can then be compared with the `end_date` of the current booking.

```
select min(end_date) next_possible_start_date
from (
    select 
        end_date,
        lead(start_date) over(partition by court_id order by start_date) next_start_date
    from booking b
    where court_id = :court_id
)
where 
    next_start_date is null 
    or next_start_date >= DATE_ADD(end_date, interval :duration minute)
```

---

**Edit**

Here is a new version of the query that adresses the use case when the court is immediatly free at the time when the search is performed:

```
select 
    court_id, 
    greatest(min(b.end_date), now()) next_possible_start_date
from bookings b
where 
    -- b.court_id = :court_id and 
    not exists (
        select 1
        from bookings b1
        where 
            b1.court_id = b.court_id
            and b1.start_date > b.end_date
            and b1.start_date < date_add(greatest(b.end_date, now()), interval ::duration minute)
)
group by court_id
```

Note: this searches for all available courts at once; you can uncomment the `where` clause to filter on a specific court.

Given this sample data:

```
court_id | start_date          | end_date           
-------: | :------------------ | :------------------
       1 | 2019-10-29 13:00:00 | 2019-10-29 13:30:00
       1 | 2019-10-29 14:00:00 | 2019-10-29 15:00:00
       2 | 2019-10-29 23:14:05 | 2019-10-30 00:14:05
       2 | 2019-10-30 01:14:05 | 2019-10-30 02:14:05
```

Court 1 is immedialty free. Court 2 is booked for next hour, then there is a 60 minutes vacancy before the next booking.

If we run the query for a duration of 60 minutes, we get:

```
court_id | next_possible_start_date
-------: | :-----------------------
       1 | 2019-10-29 23:14:05      -- available right now
       2 | 2019-10-30 00:14:05      -- available in 1 hour
```

While for 90 minutes, we get:

```
court_id | next_possible_start_date
-------: | :-----------------------
       1 | 2019-10-29 23:14:05      -- available right now 
       2 | 2019-10-30 02:14:05      -- available in 3 hours
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a13e67e9aa5c942042307e6c009522e3)**

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply! Perhaps I should've explained the conditions under which a booking is free in more detail. I think your approach does not always give me the actual next possible booking start date, if there's no other booking present. So for instance if there's a booking with `end_date=(now - 1min)` and the next booking is in one week (or there is no booking at all in the future) - the correct response would be "now" (if the other conditions hold), but if I understand your solution correctly it would return an empty result if there's no future booking on that court.

Comment: The conditions under which bookings are free are dependent on how many courts are offered at the `startDate` by someone (courts are always offered except if there are special "not-offered"-bookings on that court) and how many other bookings at the `startDate` are already free.

Comment: @FlorianPfisterer: I see your point on immediate start date. I updated my answer with a query that handle it (and a demo).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @GMB. I tried it out. It seems like if no booking matches the condition or there are no bookings, it still returns `NULL`. For example, run `select greatest(min(b.end_date), now()) from bookings b where 0;`, it will return `NULL`.

Comment: Another issue I encountered @GMB: when I try to use `next_possible_start_date` in the WHERE conditions of the main query, it throws an error `ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE: Invalid use of group function`. If I replace `next_possible_start_date` by a String describing a date, the error goes away.

Comment: @FlorianPfisterer: I don't get your point. Yes, when no booking matches the condition, then no record is returned. I tink that this is the relevant behavior. Also: you cannot use `next_possible_start_date` in the `where` clause, because it is an aggregate computation.

Comment: We have no knowledge of the *other conditions* that you mentionned since you did not describe them in your question to start with. As far as concerned, this last query in my answer is a comprehensive answer to your initial question (including your first comment).

Comment: Please check the EDIT-part of the question, I have added the exact conditions when a booking is free. For this I need to use `next_possible_start_date` in the `WHERE`-clause.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

**`Finding available slot before the last booking` :**

Find the difference between each booking with it's following one. If the difference is greater than the number of days of the new booking, you can use that slot.

**`Finding available slot after the last booking` :**

If there is no such slot, you can assign a day after the end date of the last booking.

If this query returns null, it means there is no booking for the court. You can handle that in the client side.

## Code

```
SET @c := 1; # Court id
SET @n := 2; # Number of days

/*
    Previous booking
*/
SET @i := 0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bp AS
    SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS id, startDate, endDate FROM booking
    WHERE courtId = @c
    ORDER BY startDate;

/*
    Next booking
*/
SET @i := -1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bn AS
    SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS id, startDate, endDate FROM booking
    WHERE courtId = @c
    ORDER BY startDate;


/*
    Finding available slot before the last booking (Intermediate slot).
*/
SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(bp.endDate), INTERVAL 1 DAY) INTO @si FROM
    bp
JOIN
    bn
ON bn.id = bp.id
WHERE DATEDIFF(bn.startDate, bp.endDate) > @n;

/*
    Finding available slot after the last booking
*/
SELECT DATE_ADD(MAX(endDate), INTERVAL 1 DAY) INTO @sa FROM bn;


SELECT IFNULL(@si, @sa);
```

### Using the code

Just replace the values of the variables `@c` and `@n`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is not to find free slots between bookings but to find datetimes where some conditions hold, only in part related to bookings.

Comment: @FlorianPfisterer Can you clarify the conditions a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, please see the EDIT-part of the question: The conditions under which bookings are free are dependent on how many courts are offered at the startDate by someone (courts are always offered except if there are special "not-offered"-bookings on that court) and how many other bookings overlapping the startDate are already free. This means bookings can be (and probably are) free even if there are no bookings at all in the database.